# Lo-Dash sortBy array of dates in string format

Tags: javascript, sorting, lodash

I'd like to know why lodash doesn't sort array of dates in string format as compared with plain javascript `sort()`. Is it expected behavior or a bug?

```
var array = ["2014-11-11", "2014-11-12", null, "2014-11-01", null, null, "2014-11-05"];

_.sortBy(array);
// ["2014-11-11", "2014-11-12", null, "2014-11-01", null, null, "2014-11-05"]

_.sortBy(array, function(value) {return new Date(value);});
// [null, null, null, "2014-11-01", "2014-11-05", "2014-11-11", "2014-11-12"]

array.sort();
// ["2014-11-01", "2014-11-05", "2014-11-11", "2014-11-12", null, null, null]
```

Version used: Lo-Dash v2.4.1 – Modern build.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you take a look to lodash code you may see how it's implemented. Function `_.sortBy` inside uses native `Array.prototype.sort` (see [source](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/2.4.1/dist/lodash.compat.js#L4364)). But the root is not there. More interesting is function `compareAscending` that is passed as a callback to native `sort` ([source](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/2.4.1/dist/lodash.compat.js#L282)). So in a few words your

`_.sortBy(array, function(value) {return new Date(value);});`

is converted to:

```
array.sort(function(a, b) {
    var aa = new Date(a),
        bb = new Date(b);

    if (aa !== bb) {
        if (aa > bb) { return 1; }
        if (aa < bb) { return -1; }
    }
    return aa - bb;
})
```

So why `null`s are in the beginning? Because `new Date(null)` returns `Thu Jan 01 1970 01:00:00` which is less than any other date in your array.

What about native `sort`? According to spec (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)) **The default sort order is according to string Unicode code points.** If simply - native `sort` converts items to strings and compares strings. So native sort is smth like:

```
_.sortBy(array, function(value) {return value + ''; });
```

As soon as 'null' string is always "bigger" than date string (like '2014-11-11') - `null`s will be in the tail of the result array.

Comment: You can also use `_.sortBy(array, String)`, which uses the fact that `String`, as a function, also coerces a given value to a String, just like `+''`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to use lodash to sort dates in ascending or descending order for your array of objects, you should use `_.orderBy` instead of `_.sortBy`

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#orderBy, this method allows specifying sort orders either by `'asc'` or`'desc'`

An example would be:

```
const sortedArray = _(myArray.orderBy([
  function(object) {
    return new Date(object.date);
  }],["desc"])
```