# Github API(v3): Sort search result by date created

Tags: github, github-api

I want to sort my repositories search result by the date they are created.
This might be an easy task but I have been struggling for a while.
Please help :(

Comment: You are wanting to "Sort Javascript Object Array By Date": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19430561/how-to-sort-a-javascript-array-of-objects-by-date, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40965727/sort-array-of-objects-with-date-field-by-date

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If Github API Graphql v4 is still an option, you can do this very easily, from [the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/) :

```graphql
{
  user(login: "bertrandmartel") {
    repositories(first: 100, orderBy: {field: CREATED_AT, direction: DESC}) {
      nodes {
        createdAt
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

using curl :

```bash
curl -H "Authorization: bearer token" -d '
 {
   "query": "query { user(login: \"bertrandmartel\") { repositories(first: 100, orderBy: {field: CREATED_AT, direction: DESC}) { nodes { createdAt name } } } }"
 }
' https://api.github.com/graphql
```

Answer (score 4):

For API (V3) you can include the sort qualifier in your query -  `+sort:author-date-desc` for descending and `+sort:author-date-asc` for ascending.

For example: to search all repos started by `km-poonacha` sorted ascending you can make the following search request:

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=user:km-poonacha+sort:author-date-asc
```

Ref: [Sorting Search Results](https://help.github.com/articles/sorting-search-results/)