# Sorting Organization's Repos by "newest" or "creation date"

Tags: github

There are only a few options provided by the UI to sort repositories in an organization:
[image]

Are there any options that I can use in the query to be able to sort my organization's repositories in order of either newest or oldest? It seems that the default sorts by updated time, but I want creation time.

Hypothetically something that works like this: https://github.com/orgs/github/repositories?q=sort%3Acreated-desc&type=source

Comment: Try GitHub API to perform custom sorting. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47255773/github-apiv3-sort-search-result-by-date-created . The accepted answer shows an example for sorting by create date.

Comment: replace `user(login: "bertrandmartel")` with `organization(login: "<org_name>")` in https://stackoverflow.com/a/47255971/8529250